# REGEX Match [WildCard] but not [WildCard].[WildCard]

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

Using C# Regex

### Example

Simple Input: [testA].[max] **[testB]**

Match: [testB]

Input: 5/**[test1]**  [test2].[max]  **[test3]***2 **[min]**

Match:[test1] [test3] [min]

### Definition

I want to match anything with like [Whatever] but not match [Whatever].[(min|max|mean|sum|median)]

### Attempt

This works sort of it does not match [min] on its own.

```
(?!\[((\w|[.])+)\]\.\[(min|max|mean|sum|median)\])\[((?!min|max|mean|sum|median).+?)\]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
(?<!\.)\[[A-Za-z0-9]*\](?!\.\[.*\])
```

- `(?<!\.)` - Negative lookbehind to prevent `.[max]` matching matching as well.
- `\[[A-Za-z0-9]*\]` - Match `[...]`, add other characters if necessary.
- `(?!\.\[.*\])` - Negative lookahead to ignore `[...].[...]`.

Comment: Thanks you ;) nvm on my last comment deleted it.